# Which type of sentence is this(Simple, Compound and Complex)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I am a noob and started to learn English. I studied all types of sentences and this sentence surprises me.

> Your birthday, the most exciting moment of your life, needs to be
>   celebrated with all of your friends.

Please provide some more examples.

Anyone, please give an idea?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I am confused between simple and compound. I found this Subject-Verb Agreement first time.

Comment: I think there are three verbs, exciting, needs and celebrated?

Comment: "Exciting" is an adjective.

Comment: Okay, So needs and celebrated are the verbs.

Comment: You really should include "be", so It's a complex sentence because it contains two subordinate (dependent) clauses "to be celebrated with all of your friends" (complement of "needs") and "celebrated with all of your friends" (complement of "be").

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to go through deep practice for Sentence types.